# Can not import React in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting following error :

```
xport = React;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

This my tsconfig file :

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on this issue?
I tried to change "target" to the :"es6" but It still did not work for me

Import in component :

```
 import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Register.css";
```

Comment: how did you create the project?

Comment: `import * as React from "react";`

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress create-react-app 'randomname'

Comment: @Leonardo But how will I be able to import useState and useReft after that?

Comment: `import * as React, { useState, useRef } from "react";`

Comment: try these configs ` {
   "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "dom.iterable",
    "esnext"
  ],
  "allowJs": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "module": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "noEmit": true,
  "jsx": "react"
   },
   "include": [
  "src"
   ]
 }
`

Comment: @Leonardo in that case it still gives me this kind of error : String literal expected.ts(1141

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress thank you I will try that too